# I need help on this sticks and circles logic!

Tags: symbols

[image: logic] I'm completely stuck on this logic problem, which was on a school test given by my 8th grade math teacher, who I assume wrote the problem. Can anyone help me understand it? I have tried to figure out the sticks and circles logic, but to no avail. I'd be grateful if anyone could show me how this is done, and if there is a resource to learn about this style of problem.

P.S.-The test was graded and returned (so I'm not cheating). I just didn't get the right answer, and I'm curious to figure out what it might be.

Comment: I've put this on hold because we have a rule that puzzles you didn't make yourself need to be accompanied by a full explanation of where they're from. My apologies for the fact that the notice says "off-topic"; of course this isn't at all off-topic. (There are rather silly technical reasons why this is lumped in with actual off-topic-ness.) Once you've told us where the question is from it can probably be reopened.

Comment: actually, no I don't know the answer. the two circles should be "3" by my reckoning. :(  this could be a mistake  in the puzzle.

Comment: Ok. Added source to the best of my ability.

Comment: The number associated is counting the lines and intersections, hence B.=7 is the correct answer.

Comment: The answer is the total number of objects + intersections - number of circles.

Answer (score 8):

> It is the number of straight lines added to the number of intersection points which is 7